# PREPARE TRANSACTION releasing locks?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, msdtc, 2phase-commit

I must be missing something about PostgreSQL and two phase commit with PREPARE TRANSACTION.

The following SQL :

```
BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1
```

Gives the follwing locks :

```
4092    Private 329373  acc     15/53295    RowExclusiveLock    Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092    Private 329369  acc     15/53295    RowExclusiveLock    Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092    Private 328704  acc     15/53295    RowExclusiveLock    Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092    Private 327169  acc     15/53295    RowExclusiveLock    Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092            acc 15/53295    15/53295    ExclusiveLock   Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092    Private 329377  acc     15/53295    RowExclusiveLock    Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1    
4092            acc     15/53295    ExclusiveLock   Oui 2013-06-13 18:15:55+02  UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1
```

As soon as the transaction is prepared :

```
PREPARE TRANSACTION 'TEST'
```

the lock are gone.

Because there is small delay that occurs between PREPARE and COMMIT, another query could get an older version of the record.

Is there a configuration setting to avoid this behavior or is it by design ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.2 on Windows x64 (PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit)

**EDIT 2** : Following is the full test case :

Issue the following in new session :

```
BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE person.tcities set ctyname='L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT TRANSACT' WHERE ctyid = 1
PREPARE TRANSACTION 'TEST';
```

Then in another new session :

```
SELECT * FROM person.tcities
```

You'll get the old version of the records.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Any chance you're using some elderly version?

Comment: @Graig-Ringer : I've updated my question => 9.2.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the described behaviour on PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
 CREATE TABLE prep_test AS SELECT generate_series(1,10) AS x;

 BEGIN;
 UPDATE prep_test SET x = x*10;
 PREPARE TRANSACTION 'test';
```

then in a second session:

```
 UPDATE prep_test SET x = x*20;
```

blocks, as expected, until I either `COMMIT PREPARED 'test'` or `ROLLBACK PREPARED 'test'`

I also got the expected results when testing serializable isolation:

```
A# BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
B# BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
A# INSERT INTO prep_test(x) VALUES (42);
B# INSERT INTO prep_test(x) VALUES (43);
A# SELECT count(x) FROM prep_test;
B# SELECT count(x) FROM prep_test;
A# PREPARE TRANSACTION 'test';
B# COMMIT;
```

`B` fails with a serializability error, exactly as expected. The same happens if B tries to `PREPARE TRANSACTION` too.

**After question updated with test case**:

Your test case looks fine to me, ie it should behave exactly as described and execute without error.

`PREPARE TRANSACTION` isn't a commit. You can still `ROLLBACK PREPARED`. So PostgreSQL can't show you the changed rows until you do the final `COMMIT PREPARED`, otherwise you'd get a dirty read anomaly if you read the rows then did a `ROLLBACK PREPARED`.

You'd get the same result from your test caes if you didn't `PREPARE TRANSACTION` in the first session before you ran the second command. It has nothing to do with prepared transactions. You're just not seeing rows changed by an uncommitted transaction, which is perfectly normal.

If both transactions are `SERIALIZABLE` then it's still fine. Serializability requires that there be *a* valid ordering in which the concurrent transactions could have occurred serially to produce the same results. Here, that's obvious: The `SELECT` came first, then the `UPDATE`. The transactions are *still occurring concurrently with each other* when the `SELECT` occurs because a transaction prepared with `PREPARE TRANSACTION` is still open until it's committed or rolled back.

Comment: @Graig Ringer : Update blocks but not SELECT.

Comment: @omatrot Please show the full test case in your question, because it all tests out fine here. Comment here when you've updated and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've added the full test case. I've also understood why the behavior is like it is : the MVCC locking model used by PostgreSQL. I previously worked mainly with MS Sql Server, so this is new to me.

Comment: @Graig-Ringer : You're right this has nothing to do with prepared transactions. When I say that the locks are gone, it is incorrect. They simply do not appear anymore in the locks Server Status window.